# Let $H(e^{iw})=iw$. Use this to calculate a related sum $\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I first computed the inverse Discrete time Fourier transform of H:

$$h(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} iwe^{iwn}dw$$

Using integration by parts, I got $\frac{-1}{n}$

Now, using Parseval's theorem:

$$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{-n})^2= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (iw)^2dw$$

=$$\frac{1}{2\pi}[\frac{-w^3}{3}]_{-\pi}^{\pi}$$

=$$-\frac{\pi^2}{3}$$

This seems wrong to me because the sum is supposed to be positive while this is negative.

Also, this sum from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is going through a singularity at 0. How can it be finite? Please explain.

And even after that, I need the sum from 1 to $\infty$ instead of this. I could maybe half this calculated sum to get that required value if there was no singularity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can compute $h(0)$ separately which gives you $0$, because $(\omega \mapsto i\omega)$ is an odd function.

And notice that in Parseval identity you have the integral of the square of the modulus of the function : $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |iw|^2\mbox{d}\omega$, which removes the extra minus sign you had.

Therefore you have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \leq -1} \left(\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)^2 + 0 + \sum_{n \geq 1} \left(\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)^2 &= \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |iw|^2\mbox{d}\omega \\
2\sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{1}{n^2}&=\dfrac{\pi^2}{3} \\
\sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{1}{n^2}&=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6},
\end{align*}
which is the well-known result.

Comment: I'm not sure about how to compute $h(0)$. How did you get 0 for it?

Comment: $h(0)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}i\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\omega d \omega = 0$ @RyderRude

Comment: @fonfox Thanks. I wonder why computing the integral in terms of $n$ gave the wrong value of $h(0)$. I think it's because it involves integrating $e^{jwn}$, the formula for which holds for only non-zero n.

Comment: @RyderRude yes exactly, because you cannot divide by $n$ when $n=0$. And by the way I think $h(n)=(-1)^n/n$ (which doesn't change the conclusion), because $e^{in\pi}=(-1)^n$.

Comment: yeah, you're right. I got $\frac{cos(n\pi)}{n}$ from the integral. I mistakenly substituted -1 for the cosine